# history -r has different behaviour if called by bind or if typed in command line

Tags: bash

`history -r`, used in a function, has different behaviour depending on whether it's called by command line or with bind.

With a little file called `hist.txt` containing 4 lines:

```
cat hist.txt
a
b
c
d
```

and a function called foo :

```
function foo {
  history -c && history -r ./hist.txt
}
```

If I type `foo` and then press UP key, I get the buffer filled with `d`. This is correct.

If I bind this function with `bind -x '"\eW":"foo"'` then press `ALT+W`, foo is executed but the result is different: if I press UP key I get nothing, and if I press DOWN key then I get `b`.

Is there an explanation for this, and is there perhaps a way for this `bind` to act like the first behavior described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-answer. I still don't know why history -r does not comply with bind but I found a workaround using a loop and history -s :

```
bind -x '"\eW":"dum=$(cat hist.txt) && while read j; do history -s ${j}; done <<< $dum"'
```

Only difference with history -r is that `hist.txt` file needs to end with an empty line. If not : read will not get the last line (`d`) in the provided example.